# How to update a column using group by in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables and I want to update one row from `GROUP BY` data

This is my code:

***2nd code:***

```
UPDATE [TABLE].[dbo].[Movies]
SET [NumFrames] = 
   (SELECT COUNT(ImageURL) as "Count"
    FROM [TABLE].[dbo].[Frames]
    GROUP BY Movie_Id)
GO
```

***1st code:***

```
(SELECT COUNT(ImageURL) as "Count"
FROM [TABLE].[dbo].[Frames]
GROUP BY Movie_Id
```

1st code give me a row with numbers

```
Count
 12
  6
 10
 10
 10
```

I want to insert it into `Movies.NumFrames`

2nd code give me an Error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,   !=, <, <=
>   , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please help

I'm sure it's simple

Comment: Are you saying *SQL* (which is the *Structured Query Language*), but you're really meaning **SQL Server** (the Microsoft datatabase product)? If so: please adapt your tag accordingly, and tell us what **version** of SQL Server you're using

Comment: Thanks for the comment. i was talking abut SQL server MS SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a `WHERE`-clause (`GROUP BY` is not necessary any more).
Otherwise your sub-query returns one row for each `Movie_Id`, so you have more than one row to use as source for your update.

```
UPDATE [TABLE].[dbo].[Movies]
   SET [NumFrames] = 
    ( SELECT COUNT(ImageURL) as "Count"
      FROM [TABLE].[dbo].[Frames]
      WHERE [TABLE].[dbo].[Frames].Movie_Id = [TABLE].[dbo].[Movies].Movie_Id
    )
```

Comment: +1 for answer. I think we might need to add a condition for outer update clause as well to pick only id's available in frame table, so in the end [TABLE].[dbo].[Movies].Movie_Id in (/*movies id from frames*/)

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks very very much!
I love this site :)